# Are these two parametric equations equivalent

Tags: graphing-functions, equivalence-relations, parametric

I have two parametric equations that I suspect to be equivalent. I know I need to find a bijection map between the two to find whether they are, but I'm not sure how to go about doing so.

The two curves in question are:
$$
(t^2,t)
$$
and:
$$
(2t-\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm\sqrt{8t+1}),2t-\frac{1}{4}(-1\pm\sqrt{8t+1})^2)
$$

When plotted, they seem to be identical. Can you give me any pointers as to how I could go about showing their equivalence (or lack of it)?

Comment: What is the value of $(2t-\frac 14(-1\pm\sqrt{8t+1})^2)^2$?

Comment: Thank you! (It seems so obvious in retrospect!) That's such a huge help!

Comment: It might be interesting to know where the second parametric curve came from. I could see something was related to the roots of $x^2+x-2\sqrt{t}=0$, but not quite the curve of the post exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As in my commented hint...)

Comparing $P(t)=(t^2, t)$ with

$$Q(t)=(2t-\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm\sqrt{8t+1}),2t-\frac{1}{4}(-1\pm\sqrt{8t+1})^2)$$

means that we want to see whether

$$2t-\frac{1}{2}(-1\pm\sqrt{8t+1})=(2t-\frac{1}{4}(-1\pm\sqrt{8t+1})^2)^2$$

$$=(2t-\frac 14(1\pm 2\sqrt{8t+1}+8t+1))^2$$

$$=4t^2-2t-8t^2\pm (-2)t\sqrt{8t+1}+\frac 14\pm\frac 12\sqrt{8t+1}+4t^2\pm 2t\sqrt{8t+1}+\frac 14(8t+1)+2t$$

$$=2t-\frac 12(-1\pm\sqrt{8t+1})$$

which demonstrates the required equivalence.

**However**:

(Assuming $t\in\Bbb R$) Note that the domain of $P(t)$ is $(-\infty,+\infty)$, while the domain of $Q(t)$ is $[-\frac 18,+\infty)$, so that the two formulations are only equivalent in terms of how the $x$ and $y$ coordinates relate, not in terms of the domain and range of each parametric form.

Comment: Ah, the note about the domain is helpful too—I had briefly wondered why the graph of the equation had values for when x was less than zero, unlike the graph of $(t^2,t)$. Now I can see the graph was plotting the real parts of complex values for when x was less than zero. Thank you for pointing that out.